# Getting error when trying to run server having django -channels

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels

I am trying to use django-channels in my django-project and getting this error while trying to run the server. I am following this tutorial to build chatting application.

https://gearheart.io/blog/creating-a-chat-with-django-channels/

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fb7aa2b1e18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/channels/apps.py", line 6, in <module>
    import daphne.server  # noqa
  File "/home/praneet/pral/jagrit/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 192
    async def handle_reply(self, protocol, message):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Channels 2 [dropped support](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/2.0.0.html#release-notes) for Python 2.7 and 3.4. It now requires Python 3.5 or 3.6.

The [`async def`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) statement was added in Python 3.5. You get a syntax error because you're using Python 3.4.